# How to prepare a Protocol Change Proposal?

Tags: protocol, testing

I want to know what is the procedure for preparing a protocol proposal.

From my understanding it goes like this.

Take the current Protocol src and make the changes in .ml files.
Use a script to generate a new protocol version # and Name. - This part I was not able to give the protocol hash a desired prefix.
Start a tezos node with genesis block. - I wasn't able to get ./tezos-node run --network sandbox to work with my proto source.
Create a public testnet for the protocol.
Provide bootstrappers / genesis bakers.
begin running tests.
write documentation about the proposal to share to tezos community.
inject protocol hash with a baker during proposal period.
vote yes for proposal during voting phase.
furthur testing in adoption phase.
migrate to new protocol.

I am sure there are some steps missing. If anyone has a step-by-step guide or would like to help me learn this procedure let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The best documentation available for this is:

- http://tezos.gitlab.io/developer/proposal_testing.html
- http://tezos.gitlab.io/developer/entering_alpha.html
- https://gitlab.com/romain.nl/howtos/-/blob/master/HOWTO-launch-a-test-network.md

To summarize, you'll want to:

- patch `src/proto_alpha`
- use `scripts/snapshot_alpha_and_link.sh` to copy the protocol into a new directory with the final hash
- create a branch with the result
- start a test network with your branch, using `tezos-client activate protocol` to activate your protocol
- inject your proposal on Mainnet
- communicate about your proposal

Comment: Thank you Romain for the response.  Ill keep trying.